# localhost port 8080 doesn't respond but using 127.0.0.1:8080 does work

Tags: mac-osx, localhost, local-system

When I try to access locahost:8080, I get

```
The localhost page isn’t working

localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

but if I try:

127.0.0.1:8080, I get the response I'm looking for

I believe this has something to do with the httpd (apache) that I just updated with homebrew httpd24(httpd.2.4)?

I followed the instructions for updating from this site:
https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions

Comment: does "ping localhost" resolve to 127.0.0.1 ? You can check /etc/hosts as well.

Comment: Yes, ping localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1
    127.0.0.1              localhost    
    255.255.255.255  broadcasthost

Comment: Did you have old config files which define a virtual host? Or is there anything in the apache log files? Do you see anything happening when you tail all log files and try to access localhost? "tail -f /usr/local/var/log/apache2/*"

Comment: I'm not sure, not really knowledgeable about the server configs, just fiddle until I get things working
Here is a link the result when I run the tail call: [gist file](https://gist.github.com/anthonybrown/a94bd707164934807d0ca547da8afa24)

Comment: It looks like there is still another process running which uses the ports. So I guess you would need to shut it down first

Comment: I did a ps aux | grep localhost:8080
<code><pre>
    → ps aux | grep localhost:8080 
    tony             66074   0.0  0.0  2444056    700 s003  U+   12:52PM      0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude        -dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn localhost:8080
</pre></code>

Comment: Look for the process with: "ps -aef | grep httpd | grep -v grep". Since the process of apache is called httpd and not localhost

Comment: You can kill the runnig apache with the following command: ps -aef | grep " httpd " | grep -v grep |kill $(awk '{print $2}')

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/anthonybrown/6edb0a65411c77d253876b8e51598a59) is the link to the output

Sorry for the formatting, so I should just run `kill` on all httpd process?

Comment: Yeah, since there is another apache process running, you cannot start your updated version. You need to stop or if that doesn't work kill them, before you can start your new server with apachectl start

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I'll try.
Thanks for the help, I appreciate it!

Comment: No worries, the command: * ps -aef | grep " httpd " | grep -v grep |kill $(awk '{print $2}') * Should work and do the job for you. After that you can start the new apache with * sudo apachectl -k restart *

Comment: seems to be taking a long time to run that command, nothing happening yet

Comment: I have most of Apache and PHP stuff installed with `homebrew` if that helps at all?

Comment: If it's taking a long time, then it most probably tries to restart every killed apache process. Can you just try to shut it down with: * sudo apachectl stop * and check for running processes afterwards ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49897/discussion-between-pixel-67-and-meiko-watu).

Comment: `httpd (pid 39269?) not running1

Comment: If it's OS X's built-in apache running, you can deactivate it with `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`. If that says "Could not find specified service", it's not activated so you need to look elsewhere for the source of the problem.

Comment: @GordonDavisson that killed the httpd that came with Apple but didn't resolve the localhost:8080, still have to access it via: 127.0.0.1:8080

It's strange

Comment: @pixel67 That might be an IPv6 thing. localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1 (IPv4) *and* ::1 (IPv6) *and* fe80::1%lo0 (also IPv6), so if you have apache listening only on IPv4, localhost may not reach it.

Comment: 127.0.0.1    localhost255.255.255.255                     broadcasthost
    ::1                                        localhost
    fe80::1%lo0                         localhost

Comment: that's the /ets/hosts file

Comment: localhost can also resolve to an IPv6 address while 127.0.0.1 is guaranteed to be ipv4. Your application might behave differently ipv6 vs ipv4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing *httpd24* with brew you have two completely different Apache web server environments:

1. brew's httpd24
2. the original macOS/OS X httpd

Both have different config files and apachectl (and other) binaries. The first one is installed to /usr/local/Cellar/httpd24 and its binaries are linked to /usr/local/bin. macOS' httpd related binaries are located at /usr/sbin.

Depending on your PATH variable (enter `echo $PATH` to get it) `sudo apachectl [cmd]` either controls the first or the second Apache environment.

After installing brew the default PATH should be `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` which favors brew's httpd24. You can control macOS' Apache by using the full path (/usr/sbin/apachectl) though.

If you have a different path which doesn't favor /usr/local/bin over /usr/sbin it's the other way round. To get the path of the favored *apachectl*  you can also simply enter `which apachectl`.

Check this with `/usr/local/bin/apachectl -S` which should yield:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "/usr/local/opt/httpd24"
Main DocumentRoot: "/usr/local/var/www/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "/usr/local/var/log/apache2/error_log"
Mutex default: dir="/usr/local/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/usr/local/var/run/apache2/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="daemon" id=1 not_used
Group: name="daemon" id=1 not_used
```

and `/usr/sbin/apachectl -S`

```
VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "/usr"
Main DocumentRoot: "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
Main ErrorLog: "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
Mutex default: dir="/private/var/run/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
PidFile: "/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="_www" id=70 not_used
Group: name="_www" id=70 not_used
```

There are **no** mutually used files/folders.

They also use different standard config files:

```
/usr/local/bin/apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES
Included configuration files:
  (*) /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf
```

The command doesn't work properly for the original (macOS) apachectl though and only yields: Syntax OK.

---

If you run both httpds (configuring different ports here: 80: macOS; 8080 httpd24 - check this in the respective config files) `ps -aef | grep httpd | grep -v grep` will show the following:

```
  0    76     1   0  4:54pm ??         0:00.13 /usr/local/opt/httpd24/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
  1   219    76   0  4:54pm ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd24/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
  1   220    76   0  4:54pm ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd24/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
  1   221    76   0  4:54pm ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd24/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
  1   222    76   0  4:54pm ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd24/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
  1   223    76   0  4:54pm ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd24/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
  1  4239    76   0  5:06pm ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd24/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
  0  8251     1   0  5:45pm ??         0:00.08 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
 70  8261  8251   0  5:46pm ??         0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

The first seven pids belong to httpd24, the last two to macOS' httpd - check the binary paths listed!
and `nmap localhost`:

```
Starting Nmap 7.31 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-12-22 18:00 CET
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00039s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1 fe80::1
Not shown: 499 closed ports, 498 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

In your [private chat message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34033959#34033959) you can clearly see that httpd24 **isn't** running at all, but macOS' httpd **is**.

To disable macOS' httpd simply run `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl stop` and additionally `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist` (just to be sure).

Then dump the `brew service start ...` method by stopping the service and installing a real plist daemon like recommended in the linked how-to.

```
sudo cp -v /usr/local/Cellar/httpd24/2.4.23_2/homebrew.mxcl.httpd24.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons
sudo chown -v root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.httpd24.plist
sudo chmod -v 644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.httpd24.plist
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.httpd24.plist
```

Reboot. If you still get an error connecting with localhost:8080 to your local developer site comment out `fe80::1%lo0 localhost` in /etc/hosts. In my environment it works **with** this line though.

---

After further investigations it turns out that a misconfigured web proxy (part of ESET's Internet Security/Antivirus) is the culprit. By adding a proper `localhost` exclude it should be possible to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for helping out, I tried your commands, [here](https://gist.github.com/anthonybrown/6b97c39d3277c3a012eda42cdd5911ee) is the outputs of the commands in order that you wrote them.

Comment: I used the `--privileged-port` as well

I'm almost ready to do a clean install

Comment: I don't have dnsmasq running, although I did play around with getting it setup awhile back. I did not perform mDBSResponder cache

Comment: @klonomath [here](https://gist.github.com/anthonybrown/2299cf66bd728df5a79a94b5c551bf31) is a gist of what's running

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50682/discussion-between-pixel-67-and-klanomath).